# scss theme logic in nextjs works only in certain files

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I have the strange behavior that the theme logic only works in certain files.

**Index.tsx - this wrapps my hole application**

```
<div className={styles.theme_light}>{children}</div>
```

This is the file where I have created the theme definition and the mixin methods that I can use to control the themes.

**styles/_Theme.module.scss**

```
 // theme definition
    $themes: (
      light: (
        color-primary: #30d598,
        color-background: #24bf2c,
      ),
      dark: (
        color-primary: #30d598,
        color-background: #9e247e,
      ),
    );
    
    @mixin themed() {
      @each $theme, $map in $themes {
        .theme_#{$theme} & {
          $theme-map: () !global;
          @each $key, $submap in $map {
            $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
            $theme-map: map-merge(
              $theme-map,
              (
                $key: $value,
              )
            ) !global;
          }
          @content;
          $theme-map: null !global;
        }
      }
    }
    
    @function t($key) {
      @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
    }
```

**styles/_test.module.scss**

```
@import '_Theme.module.scss';

.page_body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  @include themed() { 
    background-color: t('color-primary');
    // the background-color change to the primary color
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for me but when I try to use this logic in another scss file like below, then nothing happens.

**componets/OutlinedInput/_OutlinedInput.module.scss**

```
@import '../../../styles/_Theme.module.scss';

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  @include themed() { // the background color does not change
    background-color: t('color-primary');
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea why this behavior occurs?

Thank you in advance :)